# nosetests: how to show customized logging

Tags: python, logging, nose

I have the following python file fct.py. If I run test1() or test2() directly in python or ipython, I get:

```
In [315]: test1()
fct - fct.py[line:9] 2017-01-02 17:23:22,992 : DEBUG :  debug output

In [316]: test2()
fct - fct.py[line:9] 2017-01-02 17:23:26,393 : DEBUG :  debug output
```

If I run

```
nosetests -v fct.py
```

I get:

```
test1 logging ... ok
test2 logging ... ok
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

No logging output "debug output".

How do I obtain the logging message "debug output" in nosetests? I read nosetests -h and google around a bit but can't seem to find a solution. Thanks for any help or pointers.

```
''' fct.py ''' 
import logging

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
LOGGER.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())

def fct():
    ''' fct logging '''
    LOGGER.debug(" debug output")

def test1():
    ''' test1 logging '''
    fct()
    assert 1==1

def test2():
    ''' test2 logging '''
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    fct()
    assert 1==1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nosetests --nologcapture fct.py
```

will do the trick